# NullReferenceException on XmlSerializer.Serialize

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0, nullreferenceexception, xmlserializer

We are trying to serialize a class to XML and we get confronted with a NullReferenceException and we cant figure out why. I've looked at the Objects in the Visual Studio debugger, none of them is not initialized. All the properties in displayConfig are not null when we try to serialize, the file name is correct. We are helpless here.

You can find the code at http://pastebin.com/3RwkMMbr

The Question is: Where does this NullReferenceException come from that is thrown by the Methods Serialize and Deserialize?

EDIT:
Ok. After trying this in another application the InnerException changeded from "NullReferenceException" to something like "Could not find Assemlby $(ProjectName)". That was odd, I thought, I've added a reference to the .dll from the bin/Debug folder and suddenly it worked. I don't know why, but - no "NullReferenceException" anymore. It is serializing fine. In the original project as well.

I am confused. It is creating a strange loop in my head to reference the .dll I want to create with this code.

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: Copy-Paste to my project doesn't work. Not easy to read. What do you expect me to do what you couldn't do?

Comment: @svick: Stacktrace is here: https://pastebin.com/bnJZFjfQ

Comment: @L.B maybe we are missing something obvious. I would be happy for advice on "How to write code that is easier to read" :-) I didnt provide dummy-code with the general Idea of what is going on because I thought the mistake might be somewhere in the details of the real code. All I did was removing the parts that I am sure have nothing to do with it.
I am sorry if I have offended you.

Comment: Can you post the XML you're trying to deserialize (or something that looks a lot like it)? Also what happens if you put a breakpoint in your `ISerializable.GetObjectData` implentation?

Comment: @M.Babcock We have not been able to successful serialized something. Therefore I can't give you any XML (The Idea is that we only deserialize when the file exists (note the if(!File.Exists(configPath))). GetObjectData is not called, Breakpoint has no effect.

Comment: @ponder - Perhaps once you're able to serialize your object you will be able to deserialize it again. ;) What kind of problems are you having in the serialization?

Comment: @ponder - If you can't provide the XML you're trying to deserialize then where is it coming from?

Comment: @M.Babcock We get a "NullReferenceException" and I can't figure out why. textWriter != null, displayConfig != null, all the members of displayConfig are != null, serializer is != null. We are really out of Ideas here.
And for Deserialize - I know it cant work but if there is no XML in the file I would expect something else than a NullReferenceException. I thought it might be related. But yes, the main Problem right now is the serialization.

Comment: @M.Babcock Let us forget about the deserialization. It is obvious that it cant work. Why the Serialization is not working is, atm, the bigger question, since we are not, afaik, deserializing before we have at least once serialized.

Comment: @ponder - Sorry I was focusing on the deserialize (it's been a very long day :)). What happens if you default your `private string _StreamSource;` using `private string _StreamSource = string.Empty;`?

Comment: @M.Babcock No Problem, over here as well *smile* Nothing changes, still the same Exception.

Comment: @ponder, `I would be happy for advice on "How to write code that is easier to read" :-)` Someone else's code is always hard to read, and harder if it is large. These `:-)` s wouldn't help you so much.

Comment: @ponder - I deleted my answer because I overlooked the detail of the constructor. Any chance you can provide a simple example that duplicates your problem? I've used the `XmlSerializer` in similar situations without issue and I can't seem to find anything special about your situation that would make it throw the exception.

Comment: @M.Babock Ok, I've made some code that should be not specific to our app, but is still producing the same Mistake. You can find it here: http://pastebin.com/P5tJsqDY

I've tried it with a ConsoleApplication and - i don't know why - it is working. The code for the ConsoleApplication is here: http://pastebin.com/CPySJUA9

I can't see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I could find in the code is that accessing `StreamSource` (which the serializer does) causes stack overflow, because you're missing an underscore in the getter.

I think that unless you can provide some code that actually reproduces your error, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I've created some code that reproduces the error and should work within an empty WinForms ComponentLibrary Project. You can find the Code here: http://pastebin.com/P5tJsqDY